# Exporting Grid.MVC data to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to export the data in Grid.MVC to Excel. I used the solution in this link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325103/MVC-Grid-to-Excel-file-download?msg=5161340#xx5161340xx

it is working but I have 2 problems. first it is working in chrome but it is not working in IE. It gives me an error (file cannot be read)in IE. Second problem is when I filter the Grid the exported data in Excel is still shows all the data not the filtered data.

if that is not a good solution please provide me example for exporting Grid.MVC data to excel.

Comment: For the "file cannot be read" it's a bit of a guess, but from example I've noticed ```curContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);```
and remember having some issues with Firefox, that would cut the file name if it had spaces and therefore confuse the browser. You should definitely put the filename together in quotes, like this: ```curContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));```

Comment: That code doesn't work in **any browser** simply because it doesn't create an Excel file. It creates an HTML table with a fake extension. Any problem with that *HTML markup*, eg an unexpected `<` in some cell will break it. The code will run but no program will be able to *import* that HTML file

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicate questions that show how easy it is to create a real xlsx file in C# using a library like Epplus. There are other questions that show how to do the same in Javascript using the appropriate libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a Server-side solution**

In this case, the client-side component isn't important. Any data you pass for export, it exports it to excel file and download it. When I want to make data to export, I use the latest filter and retrieve the same data that are showing.

I hope it helps you.

- I used `GridView` to show my data.
- And also I used a simple data table. You can retrieve data from `DataBase` or wherever.
- `DataView` just helps me to filter data.
- You need to add `ClosedXML` to your project. Use this `NuGet` command: `Install-Package ClosedXML`

**aspx**

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Name or Family" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonFilter" runat="server" Text="Filter" OnClick="ButtonFilter_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="ButtonExport_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

**C# code**

```
private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private DataView dv;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeName");
    dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeFamily");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var r1 = dt.NewRow();
        r1["Id"] = i + 100;
        r1["EmployeeName"] = "Name " + i.ToString();
        r1["EmployeeFamily"] = "Family " + i.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(r1);
    }

    dv = new DataView(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = dv;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


private MemoryStream GetStream(XLWorkbook excelWorkbook)
{
    MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
    excelWorkbook.SaveAs(fs);
    fs.Position = 0;
    return fs;
}


protected void ButtonFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dv.RowFilter = $"EmployeeName LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%' OR EmployeeFamily LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%'";

    GridView1.DataSource = dv;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}


protected void ButtonExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = $"EmployeeName LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%' OR EmployeeFamily LIKE '%{TextBox1.Text}%'";

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dv.ToTable(), "Employees");
        string myName = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode("Employees.xlsx");
        MemoryStream stream = GetStream(wb);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

---

**Update: `GridMvc` version**

In this version, I used `GridMvc` but still I make Excel file in server-side

**ASPX**

```html
@model IList<GridMvcExportToExcel.Controllers.EmployeeModel>
@using GridMvc.Html

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function exportToExcel() {
        debugger;
        var txtFilter = $('#txtFilter').val(); // get the textbox value
        var url = 'http://localhost:54312/Home/ExportToExcel?txtFilter=' + txtFilter;
        location.href = url; // redirect
        return false; // cancel default redirect
    };

</script>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("txtFilter", "", new { id = "txtFilter" })
        <button type="submit">Filter</button>
    }
    <br />

    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Add(x=>x.Id).Titled ("Employee Id");
        c.Add(x=>x.Name).Titled ("First Name").Filterable(false);
        c.Add(x=>x.Family).Titled ("Last Name").Filterable(true);
    }).WithPaging(50)

    <input type="button" id="exportToExcel" value="Export to Excel" onclick="exportToExcel()" />
</div>
```

**C#**

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IList<EmployeeModel> employees = new List<EmployeeModel>();

    public HomeController()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            employees.Add(new EmployeeModel()
            {
                Id = i + 1,
                Name = "Name " + (i + 1).ToString(),
                Family = "Family " + (i + 1).ToString(),
            });
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string txtFilter)
    {
        txtFilter = txtFilter ?? "";
        var result = employees.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(txtFilter) || x.Family.Contains(txtFilter) || x.Id.ToString() == txtFilter);
        return View(result.ToList());
    }

    public void ExportToExcel(string txtFilter)
    {
        txtFilter = txtFilter ?? "";
        var result = employees.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(txtFilter) || x.Family.Contains(txtFilter) || x.Id.ToString() == txtFilter).ToList();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(result))
        {
            table.Load(reader);
        }

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(table, "Employees");
            string myName = HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode("Employees.xlsx");
            MemoryStream stream = GetStream(wb);
            HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myName);
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
    }

    private MemoryStream GetStream(XLWorkbook excelWorkbook)
    {
        MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream();
        excelWorkbook.SaveAs(fs);
        fs.Position = 0;
        return fs;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Don't* use string interpolation to create SQL statements. What happens if someone enters `'; drop table Employees; --` in TextBox1 ? The content type for `xlsx` files is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`. `application/vnd.ms-excel` is used for `xls` files

Comment: Of course, you’re right. I never do that. But here it’s a simple filter to data table. Thank’s for your notice.

Comment: @SaeidAmini Thank you, but it's not grid.Mvc package.

Comment: @xralf Is the data filtered on the server-side or client-side?

Comment: @SaeidAmini On client-side

Answer (score 1):

I have an javascript/jquery solution that works for me.

When you use grid.mvc it's add some classes to the thead and tbody, this classes needs to be removed for an correct exportation/visualization on your generated excel file. I'm using grid.mvc too, and this code export to excel, please let me know if this is working for you.

```js
<script>

    $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
        $('.grid-wrap').find('table').removeAttr('class');
        $('.grid-header').removeAttr('class');
        $('.grid-row').removeAttr('class');

        $('.grid-cell').removeAttr('data-name');
        $('.grid-cell').removeAttr('class');


        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('.grid-wrap').html());

       
       //MakeAnyFunctionToReloadThePageToGetTheClassesAgain();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

</script>
```

```html
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    
    columns.Add(foo => foo.Date).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(foo => foo.User).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(foo => foo.Controller).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(foo => foo.Action).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(foo => foo.ActionType).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(foo => foo.JsonObject).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
}).WithMultipleFilters()

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnExport">export csv</button>
```

Comment: This won't produce an Excel file. At bets it creates an HTML table with a fake extension that Excel may or *may not* be able to import and convert

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the parameters from url. 
Then build your own service on back end, which gets the parameters and exports to excel

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
let allParams = params.getAll('grid-filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following header in your response, it will be downloaded with proper type

> data:application/vnd.ms-excel

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party here but I have found a solution that will work using the inbuilt `filtering` options of the `GridMvc` plugin. This solution DOES not require any client side manipulations or custom filter applying. This is how you go about it.

When you install the plugin, it generates a `partial` view called: `_Grid.cshtml` which is found at: `~/Views/Shared/_Grid.cshtml` location.

Now I had observed that everytime you invoke an event on the grid, this partial view is called and I then debugged into the flow and found that the `Model` in question has different properties like `RenderOptions`, `ItemsToDisplay` etc.

So I found that the filtered data is also stored but not directly in a property. There is a property called: `ItemsToDisplay` but unfortunately if you apply `paging` on the grid then it will only store the first `n` items where `n` is the paging limit.

Then finally I had to resort to `reflection` to get the entire filtered list which impacts the performance of the grid but not very much and it will get the job done.

_Grid.cshtml:

```
@using GridMvc.Columns
@using System.Reflection;
@model GridMvc.IGrid
@{ 
    try
    {
        Type t = typeof(GridMvc.Html.GridHtmlOptions<MyModel>);
        FieldInfo[] fi = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        foreach (FieldInfo info in fi)
        {
            if (info.Name == "_source")
            {
                object _source = info.GetValue(Model);
                PropertyInfo gridItemsProperty = _source.GetType().GetProperty("GridItems");
                object gridItemsData = gridItemsProperty.GetValue(_source);
                //Set the filtered list here in Session
                Session["CurrentFilteredGridForExcelExport"] = (IEnumerable<MyModel>)(gridItemsData);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

@if (Model.RenderOptions.RenderRowsOnly)
{
    @RenderGridBody();
}
else
{
    <div class="grid-mvc" data-lang="@Model.Language" data-gridname="@Model.RenderOptions.GridName" data-selectable="@Model.RenderOptions.Selectable.ToString().ToLower()" data-multiplefilters="@Model.RenderOptions.AllowMultipleFilters.ToString().ToLower()">
        <div class="grid-wrap">
            <table class="table table-striped grid-table">
                @* Draw grid header *@
                <thead>
                    @RenderGridHeader()
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @RenderGridBody()
                    @RenderGridFooter()
                </tbody>
            </table>
            @RenderGridFooter()
        </div>
    </div>
}
@helper RenderGridBody()
{
    if (!Model.ItemsToDisplay.Any())
    {
        <tr class="grid-empty-text">
            <td colspan="@Model.Columns.Count()">
                @Model.EmptyGridText
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (object item in Model.ItemsToDisplay)
        {
            <tr class="grid-row @Model.GetRowCssClasses(item)">
                @foreach (IGridColumn column in Model.Columns)
                {
                    @column.CellRenderer.Render(column, column.GetCell(item))
                }
            </tr>
        }
    }
}
@helper RenderGridHeader()
{
    if (Model.RenderOptions.ShowGridItemsCount)
    {
            <div class="grid-itemscount">
                <span class="grid-itemscount-label">@Model.RenderOptions.GridCountDisplayName:</span>
                <span class="grid-itemscount-caption">@Model.ItemsCount</span>
            </div>
    }

    <tr>
        @foreach (IGridColumn column in Model.Columns)
        {
            @column.HeaderRenderer.Render(column)
        }
    </tr>
}
@helper RenderGridFooter()
{
    <div class="grid-footer">
        @if (Model.EnablePaging && Model.Pager != null)
        {
            @Html.Partial(Model.Pager.TemplateName, Model.Pager)
        }
    </div>
}
```

And finallllllyy, you can export this filtered grid on your `Controller` side like this:

```
public void ExportToExcel()
{
    List<MyModel> mymodel= new List<MyModel>();
    if(Session["CurrentFilteredGridForExcelExport"] != null)
    {
        var datasetFromSession = (IEnumerable<MyModel>)(Session["CurrentFilteredGridForExcelExport"]);
        mymodel = datasetFromSession.ToList();
    }
    
    //Use your export logic with this dataset   
}
```

Hope this helps someone who is still using this grid plugin. Cheers!